# Copy data from a variable table

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to do a report and creating a macro to copy the data from one file to another.

I cannot figure out how to copy the data since the table I need to get my data from varies.

Example one:

[image: Example one]

What I need to copy is what is below the Alarm text.

But in, example one, I have no critical alarms but there are files that may have. Same applies to major/minor/warning.

The max of lines below the Alarm text are 3, but I can have 1/2/3 or even none.

[image: Example 2]

In example 2, I have no data.

[image: Example 3]

Here I have 2 critical and 3 on all other categories.

I know this may be a weird question, but I have no idea in how to find the these values, since they may vary so much.

All help is appreciated

Here is the code i have, but i am missing the important part,

```
          Sub Copy()



Dim wbOpen As Workbook
Dim wbMe As Workbook
Dim vals As Variant

Set wbMe = ThisWorkbook
Set wbOpen = Workbooks.Open("C:\XXX\Core")

'MSS

     vals = wbOpen.Sheets("MSS02NZF").Range("A2:B260").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("MSS02NZF").Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                 Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


       '  wbOpen.Sheets(1).Range("A2:B260").Copy
   ' wbMe.Sheets(1).Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                 Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

     'MME
  vals = wbOpen.Sheets("MME01NZF").Range("A2:H260").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("MME01NZF").Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                 Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


                     'CSCF
  vals = wbOpen.Sheets("CSCF").Range("A2:H2060").Copy
wbMe.Sheets("CSCF").Range("B5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, _
                 Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53548584/edit) to add the code you have so far?

Comment: I did, still it is just looking for specific cells, cannot find a way to get the value if the cell order will change

Comment: You can't just hard-code the cells. You need a loop that starts at the top and reads the content of column A until it locates the "alarm" marker - then you need code that starts at that line and works out at which line to stop. Now you know where to start and where to stop, you can build a range address to copy the values from. Keep looping until two consecutive rows are found empty in A... or something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify to your own need; code is using A:B as your source, and pastes the results in C:D.

```
Sub test()
    Dim lrow As Long, alarmRow() As Long, alarmEnd() As Long
    Dim count As Long, count2 As Long, rowcount As Long

    ReDim alarmRow(1 To Application.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "Alarm"))
    ReDim alarmEnd(1 To UBound(alarmRow))

    With Worksheets("Sheet4") 'Change this to the Sheetname of your source.
        lrow = .Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For x = 1 To lrow Step 1
            If .Range("A" & x).Value = "Alarm" Then 'Change "A" column to where your source data is.
                count = count + 1
                alarmRow(count) = x + 1
            ElseIf .Range("A" & x).Value = "" Then 'Change "A" column to where your source data is.

                count2 = count2 + 1
                alarmEnd(count2) = x
            End If
            alarmEnd(UBound(alarmEnd)) = lrow
        Next

        For x = 1 To UBound(alarmRow) Step 1
            lrow = .Cells(Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            rowcount = alarmEnd(x) - alarmRow(x)
            .Range("C" & lrow & ":D" & lrow + rowcount).Value = .Range("A" & alarmRow(x) & ":B" & alarmEnd(x)).Value ' Change A/B to where your source data is, and C/D to where you want to put the list.
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

It's a bit of a mess, but here's how it works:
It'll look at the list where the word "Alarm" is. Once it finds it, the row number the word is in is registered to an Array. The row of the blank space is also taken to another array. This will serve as the range when copying the data.

Comment: Thabn you so much, i will test it out! You guys are awesome. Thank you

Comment: Is there  a way that , when copying the information dosen't replace the one that if already pasted?

Comment: Source data isn't being changed here, it's just pasting the list on Columns C & D. Modify the code so that it fits your needs, like where the data will be pasted at.

Comment: ok, thank you very much understood thank so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Array of Arrays feat. 3-dimensional Jagged Arrays

```
Option Explicit

'*******************************************************************************
' Purpose:  If not open, opens a specified workbook and pastes specific data
'           found in two columns from several worksheets into a range specified
'           by a cell in worksheets with the same name in this workbook.
'*******************************************************************************
Sub CopyPasteArray()
'***************************************
  ' List of Worksheet Names in Both Workbooks
  Const cStrWsName As String = "MSS02NZF,MME01NZF,CSCF"
  ' Separator in List of Names of Worksheets in Both Workbooks
  Const cStrSplit As String = ","
  ' Path of Workbook to Be Copied From
  Const cStrSourcePath As String = "C:\XXX"
  ' Name of Workbook to Be Copied From
  Const cStrSourceName As String = "Core.xls"
  ' Address of First Row Range to Be Copied From
  Const cStrSourceFirst As String = "A2:B2"
  ' Target Top Cell Address to Be Pasted Into
  Const cStrTopCell As String = "B5"
  ' Search String
  Const cStrSearch As String = "Alarm"
  ' Target Columns
  Const cIntTargetCols As Integer = 2 ' Change to 3 to include Type of Error.

'***************************************
  Dim objWbSource As Workbook         ' Source Workbook

  Dim vntWsName As Variant            ' Worksheet Names Array
  Dim vntSourceAA As Variant          ' Source Array of Arrays
  Dim vntTargetAA As Variant          ' Target Array of Arrays
  Dim vntTargetRows As Variant        ' Each Target Array Rows Array
  Dim vntTarget As Variant            ' Each Target Array

  Dim blnFound As Boolean             ' Source Workbook Open Checker
  Dim lngRow As Long                  ' Source Array Arrays Rows Counter
  Dim intCol As Integer               ' Source Array Arrays Columns Counter
  Dim intArr As Integer               ' Worksheets and Arrays Counter
  Dim lngCount As Long                ' Critical Data Counter
  Dim lngCount2 As Long               ' Critical Data Next Row Counter
  Dim strPasteCell As String

'***************************************
  ' Paste list of worksheets names into Worksheet Names Array.
  vntWsName = Split(cStrWsName, cStrSplit)

'***************************************
  ' Check if Source Workbook is open.
  For Each objWbSource In Workbooks
    If objWbSource.Name = cStrSourceName Then
      Set objWbSource = Workbooks(cStrSourceName)
      blnFound = True ' Workbook is open.
      Exit For        ' Stop checking.
    End If
  Next
  ' If Source Workbook is not open, open it.
  If blnFound = False Then
    Set objWbSource = Workbooks.Open(cStrSourcePath & "\" & cStrSourceName)
  End If

'***************************************
  ' Paste data from Source Workbook into Source Array of Arrays.
  ReDim vntSourceAA(UBound(vntWsName))
  For intArr = 0 To UBound(vntWsName)
    With objWbSource.Worksheets(vntWsName(intArr))
      vntSourceAA(intArr) = _
        .Range( _
          .Range(cStrSourceFirst).Cells(1, 1) _
          , .Cells( _
              .Range( _
                .Cells(1, .Range(cStrSourceFirst).Column) _
                , .Cells(Rows.Count, .Range(cStrSourceFirst).Column _
                  + .Range(cStrSourceFirst).Columns.Count - 1)) _
                    .Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=.Range(cStrSourceFirst).Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
                ).Row _
              , .Range(cStrSourceFirst).Column _
                  + .Range(cStrSourceFirst).Columns.Count - 1 _
              ) _
          ).Value2
    End With
  Next
  ' The Source Array of Arrays is a 3-dimensional (jagged) array containing
  ' a 0-based 1-dimensional array containing an 'UBound(vntWsName)' number of
  ' 1-based 2-dimensional arrays.

'***************************************
  ' Count the number of critical data rows to determine size
  ' of each Target Array.
  ReDim vntTargetRows(UBound(vntWsName))
  For intArr = 0 To UBound(vntSourceAA)
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(vntSourceAA(intArr), 1)
      If vntSourceAA(intArr)(lngRow, 1) = cStrSearch Then
        For lngCount2 = lngRow + 1 To UBound(vntSourceAA(intArr), 1)
          If vntSourceAA(intArr)(lngCount2, 1) <> "" Then
'            Debug.Print vntSourceAA(intArr)(lngCount2, 1)
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
           Else
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
    vntTargetRows(intArr) = lngCount
    lngCount = 0
  Next

'***************************************
  ' Copy critical data into each Target Array and paste it into
  ' Target Array of Arrays.
  ReDim vntTargetAA(UBound(vntWsName))
  For intArr = 0 To UBound(vntSourceAA)
    ReDim vntTarget(1 To vntTargetRows(intArr), 1 To cIntTargetCols)
    For lngRow = 1 To UBound(vntSourceAA(intArr), 1)
      If vntSourceAA(intArr)(lngRow, 1) = cStrSearch Then
        If cIntTargetCols = 3 Then
          lngCount = lngCount + 1
          vntTarget(lngCount, 1) = vntSourceAA(intArr)(lngRow - 1, 1)
          lngCount = lngCount - 1
        End If
        For lngCount2 = lngRow + 1 To UBound(vntSourceAA(intArr), 1)
          If vntSourceAA(intArr)(lngCount2, 1) <> "" Then
'            Debug.Print vntSourceAA(intArr)(lngCount2, 1)
            lngCount = lngCount + 1
            vntTarget(lngCount, cIntTargetCols - 1) _
                = vntSourceAA(intArr)(lngCount2, 1)
            vntTarget(lngCount, cIntTargetCols) _
                = vntSourceAA(intArr)(lngCount2, 2)
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
           Else
            Exit For
          End If
        Next
      End If
    Next
    vntTargetAA(intArr) = vntTarget
    lngCount = 0
  Next

'***************************************
  ' Clean up
  Erase vntTarget
  Erase vntTargetRows
  Erase vntSourceAA

'***************************************
  ' Paste each Target Array into each of this workbook's worksheet's ranges,
  ' which are starting at the specified cell (cStrTopCell) if no data is below,
  ' or else at the first empty cell found searching from the bottom.
  For intArr = 0 To UBound(vntWsName)
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(vntWsName(intArr))
      If .Cells(Rows.Count, .Range(cStrTopCell).Column + cIntTargetCols - 2) _
          .End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
        ' No data in column
        strPasteCell = cStrTopCell
       Else
        ' Find first empty cell searching from bottom.
        strPasteCell = _
            .Cells( _
              .Range( _
                .Cells(1, .Range(cStrTopCell).Column) _
                , .Cells(Rows.Count, .Range(cStrTopCell).Column _
                  + cIntTargetCols - 1)) _
                    .Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=.Range(cStrTopCell).Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, Lookat:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
                ).Row + 1 _
              , .Range(cStrTopCell).Column _
            ).Address
        ' First empty cell is above Target Top Cell Address.
        If Range(strPasteCell).Row < Range(cStrTopCell).Row Then _
            strPasteCell = cStrTopCell
      End If
      ' Paste into range.
      .Range(strPasteCell).Resize( _
          UBound(vntTargetAA(intArr)) _
          , _
          UBound(vntTargetAA(intArr), 2) _
          ) = vntTargetAA(intArr)
    End With
  Next

'***************************************
  ' Clean up
  Erase vntTargetAA
  Erase vntWsName
  Set objWbSource = Nothing

End Sub
'*******************************************************************************
```