# How to check column for duplicate values, then merge adjacent columns if found?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that checks for duplicate values in a column, then merges those rows if found.

I have tried using a loop to check each cell and `cell.Offset(1,0)` and if they are equal, merge them. Then copy the formatting from that column to an adjacent column.

This image shows what I am trying to accomplish.
[image]

I am only trying to merge one column (E) but the issue is it only checks two cells at a time, so it doesnt merge 5 of the same values. It also messes up if the last row is merged. Once the checked column is merged I am just going to copy formatting to the adjacent appropriate columns.

```html
Sub Merge()

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each cell In Range("E1:E" & lastRow)
        If cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = cell.Value Then
           Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: This question has been asked here before by many others. Have you tried taking a look?

Comment: Maybe you can adjust this [Row Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279695/how-do-you-merge-same-value-columns-using-vba/54280646#54280646).

Comment: Any code you tried so far? When do you consider rows as to be merged? Only if the Project ID and Acct is equal? If yes what about differences in the remaining columns? What should happen with them when you merge the rows?

Comment: @Storax I just added the code that I tried making. I am only trying to merge one column (E) but the issue is it only checks two cells at a time, so it doesnt merge 5 of the same values. It also messes up if the last row is merged.

Comment: @urdearboy Yes I have looked at many pages of similar questions to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

## merge cells vertically

This code checks the cells of each row and merges cells vertically, if they have the same value (also formulas whith same resulting value!):

```
Sub MergeCellsVertically()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim currentRng As Range
    Dim usedRows As Long, usedColumns As Long
    Dim currentRow As Long, currentColumn As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    usedRows = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    usedColumns = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=ws.Cells(1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    For currentColumn = 1 To usedColumns
        For currentRow = usedRows To 2 Step -1
            Set currentRng = ws.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn)
            If currentRng.Value <> "" Then
                If currentRng.Value = currentRng.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
                    currentRng.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(2, 1).Merge
                End If
            End If
        Next currentRow
    Next currentColumn
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    Set currentRng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

As your example shows a non-uniform structure, this may be a good solution. If you just want to decide by one row, which neighbor-cells to merge, keep in mind, that only the content of the upper left cell of a merged area "survives".

If you want to address the content of a merged area, then `currentRng.MergeArea.Cells(1)` will always represent the first cell of the merged area, where the content is.

## unmerge

```
Sub UnmergeCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim usedRows As Long, usedColumns As Long
    Dim currentRng As Range, tempRng As Range
    Dim currentRow As Long, currentColumn As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    usedRows = ws.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row + ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
    usedColumns = ws.UsedRange.Cells(1).Column + ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count - 1
    
    For currentRow = 1 To usedRows
        For currentColumn = 1 To usedColumns
            Set currentRng = ws.Cells(currentRow, currentColumn)
            If currentRng.MergeCells Then
               Set tempRng = currentRng.MergeArea
               currentRng.MergeArea.UnMerge
               currentRng.Copy tempRng
            End If
        Next currentColumn
    Next currentRow
    
    Set tempRng = Nothing
    Set currentRng = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

As the `Find` function is bad in finding the last used column or row in merged cells, I use the standard `UsedRange` instead. Be aware, that unmerged (duplicated) formulas may be unexpected.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried that code both with and without headers and filters but it doesnt seem to do anything when run. There are no errors it just doesnt merge anything.

Also, I added some more information in my original post if it would be helpful to explain what im trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you very much! One final question: How would I modify this to only check one defined column, instead of looping through each column?

Comment: If you set e. g. `currentColumn = 5` at the beginning, and delete the code rows `For currentColumn = 1 To usedColumns` and `Next currentColumn`, then it works on column E only. And please consider to accept this answer :)