# Procedure too large when unmerge columns

Tags: excel, vba

With the following lines of code I want to unmerge the two columns (A,B), but when I run the macro I have an error "procedure too large", because I think there is repetitive code. Please, how can I make this code to work! I have 6215 lines of code with same repetitive code, like the one attached. Thanks

```
 Columns("A:B").Select
Range("A626").Activate
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
    .MergeCells = True
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .MergeCells = True
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .MergeCells = True
End With
With Selection
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .WrapText = True
    .Orientation = 0
    .AddIndent = False
    .IndentLevel = 0
    .ShrinkToFit = False
    .MergeCells = True
End With
With Selection
  ..............
```

Comment: What is the code doing?  You are doing repeated actions on the same selection.  The way the code is, the only pertinent bit is the last with block

Comment: The code is unmerging the two columns (A;B), that's all. The unmerging I've made it using Record macro.

Comment: *Columns("A:B").Select* and *Selection.MergeCells = True* doesn't tell me you're unmerging cells

Comment: You've merged the entire column? Why?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54492850/10908769) how to unmerge vertically

Comment: The two columns are merged, and I want to unmerge them, then Delete column B - which has no data in it, only the column A remains with some data in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete all your duplicate code and try this.

```
Sub test()
    Range("A1:B626").UnMerge
    Columns(2).Delete
End Sub
```